# How do I make my javascript code with some dependencies, reusable?

Tags: javascript, code-reuse

I'd like to ask this question in the most general sense possible. So, I won't be including any code in this question.

When I first joined this company I work in, I wrote some code to build a widget based off kendo grid, along with a set of requirements. So, I built that widget with some dependencies such as underscorejs, jquery and kendo.

At the time, it seemed great.

Now that I've transitioned to a new project, I need to make the code I wrote as reusable as possible. The requirement, is to simply take that code and plug it anywhere and it should work. My boss is asking me to remove those dependencies but I'd really rather not. Is there any way I can create a reusable grid widget  that still utilizes those dependencies within it?

Comment: If you use some other library, than it is dependent on that library, its a fact. So you can stop using that library - than it is really independent, or you can build your code with that libraries into file - using some js builder (r.js for instance), or make your code dependent on the other libraries using some package manager ([bower](http://bower.io/) for instance)

Comment: I don't mind including my JS libraries into my custom plugin file. But then again, is file size something to be concerned about?

Comment: Are you asking if you can write something that depends on another thing without making it depend on another thing? If your code has dependencies, than it has dependencies... No way around it. You could integrate the dependencies into your code itself or do the work that is done in dependencies yourself but that would just be doing unnecessary work and be dumb. If the problem is that your team is having problems managing dependencies, the solution to that is using Bundle Managers like Require.js, Webpack, Browserify etc...

Comment: File size is something to be concerned about, but in my opinion, there is no golden rule in this, if I say: "yes, build everything into one file" you can end up with really big file, and with many stuff you don't need, if I say: "no, do not mix everything into one file, rather request each file separately", you can end up with too many requests.